# Build a logistic model that fits two curves in R

Tags: regression, r, logistic, nonlinear-regression, nls

The relation between my dependent variable y and my independent variable x can be described by a logistic regression like:

```
mod<-nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, asymp, infl, slope1), data = dat) # y~asymp/(1+exp((infl-x)/slope1))
```

However, I have two categories A and B for which I want my logistic model to fit two curves. For that, I created two dummy variables xA and xB (for an observation from categoryA xA=1 and xB=0, for an observation from categoryB xA=0 and xB=1):

```
print(dat,row.names=F)
 category    y    x xA xB
        A 0.33 1.92  1  0
        A 0.42 2.22  1  0
        A 0.50 2.87  1  0
        A 0.52 3.89  1  0
        A 0.63 4.40  1  0
        B 0.39 1.92  0  1
        B 0.55 2.22  0  1
        B 0.61 2.87  0  1
        B 0.70 3.89  0  1
        B 0.81 4.40  0  1
        B 0.35 1.92  0  1
        B 0.43 2.22  0  1
        B 0.56 2.87  0  1
        B 0.58 3.89  0  1
        B 0.65 4.40  0  1
        A 0.37 1.92  1  0
        A 0.44 2.22  1  0
        A 0.54 2.87  1  0
        A 0.56 3.89  1  0
        A 0.64 4.40  1  0
        A 0.37 1.92  1  0
        A 0.46 2.22  1  0
        A 0.61 2.87  1  0
        A 0.62 3.89  1  0
        A 0.70 4.40  1  0
        B 0.35 1.92  0  1
        B 0.41 2.22  0  1
        B 0.52 2.87  0  1
        B 0.54 3.89  0  1
        B 0.63 4.40  0  1
        B 0.40 1.92  0  1
        B 0.44 2.22  0  1
        B 0.62 2.87  0  1
        B 0.64 3.89  0  1
        B 0.76 4.40  0  1
        B 0.37 1.92  0  1
        B 0.46 2.22  0  1
        B 0.49 2.87  0  1
        B 0.38 1.92  0  1
        B 0.48 2.22  0  1
        B 0.58 2.87  0  1
        B 0.64 3.89  0  1
        B 0.68 4.40  0  1
        A 0.38 1.92  1  0
        A 0.43 2.22  1  0
        A 0.53 2.87  1  0
        A 0.59 3.89  1  0
        A 0.71 4.40  1  0
        A 0.39 1.92  1  0
        A 0.45 2.22  1  0
        A 0.56 2.87  1  0
        A 0.63 3.89  1  0
        A 0.75 4.40  1  0
```

In the next step, I want to fit my model just as above but with the fitting parameters defined as:

```
asymp<-xA*asympA + xB*asympB
infl<-xA*inflA + xB*inflB
scal<-xA*slope1A + xB*slope1B
```

meaning, that I have six fitting parameters now: asympA, asympB, inflA, inflB, slope1A, and slope1B to get two curves. I am struggling with the implementation in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nlme package has a function designed for this:

```
library(nlme)
mod <- gnls(y ~ SSlogis(x, asymp, infl, slope1), data = dat)

mod1 <- update(mod, params = asymp + infl + slope1 ~ category, start = c(rbind(coef(mod), 0)))
summary(mod1)
# Generalized nonlinear least squares fit
#   Model: y ~ SSlogis(x, asymp, infl, slope1) 
#   Data: dat 
#         AIC       BIC   logLik
#   -156.8201 -143.0281 85.41006
# 
# Coefficients:
#                         Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
# asymp.(Intercept)   0.6991517 0.0593734 11.775495  0.0000
# asymp.categoryB     0.0100523 0.0726548  0.138357  0.8905
# infl.(Intercept)    1.7528934 0.1389747 12.613037  0.0000
# infl.categoryB      0.0178324 0.1721263  0.103601  0.9179
# slope1.(Intercept)  0.9745779 0.3515084  2.772559  0.0079
# slope1.categoryB   -0.1324611 0.4250066 -0.311668  0.7567
# 
#  Correlation: 
#                    as.(I) asym.B in.(I) infl.B s1.(I)
# asymp.categoryB    -0.817                            
# infl.(Intercept)    0.555 -0.453                     
# infl.categoryB     -0.448  0.494 -0.807              
# slope1.(Intercept)  0.926 -0.756  0.284 -0.229       
# slope1.categoryB   -0.766  0.911 -0.235  0.194 -0.827
# 
# Standardized residuals:
#         Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
# -2.26629736 -0.57085257 -0.03475581  0.42981706  2.54903046 
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.05128397 
# Degrees of freedom: 53 total; 47 residual
```

This uses treatment contrasts, i.e., `asymp.categoryB` is the difference between the `asymp` parameters of categories B and A.

You can even test easily if the two fits are significantly different:

```
anova(mod, mod1)
#     Model df       AIC       BIC   logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
#mod      1  4 -160.3191 -152.4379 84.15953                        
#mod1     2  7 -156.8201 -143.0281 85.41006 1 vs 2 2.501073  0.4751
```

You can change the `params` formula, e.g., to have only one or several parameters dependent on the category.

Comment: That is very helpful, thanks a lot!

Comment: One additional question: if I want to compare 3 categories instead of 2, do I have to code it in a way that I always compare two categories to each other or can I add another level (i.e., additional 0) to 'start', like:
mod1 <- update(mod, params = asymp + infl + slope1 ~ category, start = c(rbind(coef(mod), 0,0)))

Comment: Yes, you can add an additional 0 for each additional level of category. If not all parameters depend on the category, you need to remove some zeros.